# I can't use the invokeHTTP with Post method on NIFI

Tags: java, post, apache-nifi

I have no problem making NIFI post type requests. In the articles I've seen, I used the "invokeHTTP" component, with a "post" configuration inside it. I need to send a JSON to a fixed address, and invokeHTTP does not work. You can do the same thing with POSTMAN and it works, however in NIFI I can not.

I placed the request body in the "Put Response Body In Attribute" field.

The design can be done with CORS do not disturb (The project and the NIFI are in local network, in port 8081 and 8088 respectively).

I would like to know if anyone has any hints as to why my project does not receive a NIFI request, but receives from POSTMAN. Can I, be setting something wrong ...

Comment: Could you please post your question in English

Comment: Sorry, i've edited the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the issue is the request body. It sounds like you are putting the request body in the attribute specified in the *Put Response Body In Attribute* property.

For `InvokeHTTP` the flowfile ***contents*** are included as the body of the request.

Place the JSON you want to send via an HTTP POST in the content of the flowfile prior to the flowfile reaching your `InvokeHTTP` processor.

The *Put Response Body In Attribute* property specifies that the HTTP response body should be written to a named flowfile attribute as part of the input flowfile (rather than the default behavior, which is to generate a new output flowfile with the content of the HTTP response).

Comment: Thank you, but I did it differently. I got the GenerateFlowFile processor and put the JSON there. I then plugged it into the Extract text processor, and then called InvokeHTTP. It worked.

Comment: Glad it is working for you! I suspect it would work without the ExtractText step. ExtractText will copy all or part of the flow file content (based on the regular expression used) to an attribute, but the JSON is still in the flow file content, you've just copied it. InvokeHTTP is using the JSON from the flow file content. So if you did GenerateFlowFile >> InvokeHTTP it should also work.